# Want to add trading hours in "Enter trade when price close above 20 + 200 EMA, close when price close below 20 EMA or close above bb high"

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In the script "Enter trade when price close above 20 + 200 EMA, close when price close below 20 EMA or close above bb high" I want to initiate trade 10 minutes once the NSE opens (i.e., at 0925) and closes all open positions (Universal exit 10 minutes the exchange closes (i.e., at 01520). How can I do that? Please help.

tradeTimes = input.session("0925-1520", title="Trading Times")

I want to use 5 min time frame.
Initiate trade AFTER 0925
Closes all trades (Universal exit AT OR AFTER 1520
Indian Standard Time

Comment: you already get answer, but didn't accept it. Why should we spend time if you don't participate ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where do you need help?

Comment: As per pine script v5 manual I added:                   tradeTimes = input.session("0925-1520", title="Trading Times") But it's not working. Not sure about Universal exit either.

Comment: I even tried: session = input("0925-1520")
t = time(timeframe.period, session) As a result in the dialogue box a new label "input" appeared in which the session time was mentioned but trades were not taken accordingly.

Comment: I want to add session in one of the scripts I found: "Enter trade when price close above 20 + 200 EMA, close when price close below 20 EMA or close above bb high"